# RNMK - Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native

After upgrading my project to React-Native 0.26, the app crashing with the following error :

> "Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined"

It crashes in the Switch.js file, which belongs to the React-Native-Material-Kit package.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ahh, it's because React-Native is moving fast! Too fast in my option. In 25 we saw this warning:

**Deprecations**

Requiring React API from react-native is now deprecated - 2eafcd4 0b534d1

Instead of:

```
import React, { Component, View } from 'react-native';
```

you should now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
```

And just one release later in 26 this is now a [breaking change](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.26.0)

You can try this [codemod](https://github.com/sibeliusseraphini/codemod-RN24-to-RN25) if you dare. I'm just doing a manual change.

Comment: A manual change of all the RNMK component files, as you described, is what I used to temporarily solve this problem until a package update.