# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to share the same codebase, so I wrote my code in a `index.js` file, and I've put the same code in the `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` file.
This is the code in `index.ios.js`:

```
'use strict';

    import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
    import MYCLASS from './index';

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('MYCLASS', () => MYCLASS);
```

This is some of the code in `index.js`:

```
export default class MYCLASS extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
          my text
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree you'll need to modify that import of `React` however it doesn't look like that removes the error. Based on my testing it looks like the module bundler is having a tough time with the `index.js` in the root of the app. If you change that import to:

`import MYCLASS from './index.js';`

then it will work fine. Anything else (`./`, `./index`) will result in that error.

I would recommend that you rename that `index.js` to something else like `App.js` `Main.js` etc and update the import statement accordingly. Use `index.js` when you want to expose resources under an organized namespace (directory).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change how you import React.

See this other answer for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37415044/158525